# Python: run xdg-open in background

Tags: python, terminal, operating-system, subprocess

I've console application on Python. I try to use xdg-open and run it in background, but I can't. I tried

```
os.system('xdg-open http://google.com &')
subprocess.call('xdg-open http://google.com &', shell=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by

> but I can't

because it works for me. I imagine, however, that you're complaining that the parent process does not close until the child has.

That code is, however, an outdated practice (if it ever was in favour); the modern equivalent would be

```
process = subprocess.Popen(['xdg-open', 'Dunno.png'])
```

Instead of asking the shell to fork for you, this runs in the background from the start without ever passing through a shell. This should deal with the problem above, too.

If you want to capture `sys.stdout`, you can use

```
process = subprocess.Popen(['xdg-open', 'Dunno.png'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

which redirects the output of the process' stdout and stderr to buffers. (You can access those buffers with `process.stdout` and `process.stderr` and communicate either by reading and writing to those or using `process.communicate`.

You can get the return code with `process.returncode`.

If your problem is not this, a problem description (traceback?) would be useful. It's also worth checking that the behaviour of using xdg-open in the shell is what you expect.